# Sending a Promise as an HTTP response

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to understand promises in javascript better. I understand the basic syntax where the client uses promises for asynchronous tasks like e.g.

```js
async function fetchMovies() {
  const response = await fetch('/movies');
  // waits until the request completes...
  console.log(response);
}
```

As far as I understand fetch returns a promise that as soon as the api --here /movies-- responds, is resolved.

I'm wondering if there is any usecase where the API endpoint itself returns a promise as anresponse to an HTTP request. Something like

```js
...
const app = express();
...
app.get('/',function (req, res) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        ...heavy work here (possibly calling another fetch or smth)
        resolve({"msg":smth}); 
    })
   
    return res.send(promise);
});
```

From the perspective of the client calling the API not much would change, since it gets a promise and has to wait for it to resolve before doing anything with its response.
But the API would send the promise immediatly and then have a free cpu for doing other stuff.

My guess is that this is not really working as I have not seen it anywhere.
Probably the callback from resolving promises only makes sense inside an API (or client) but not across them, but I wanted to put it out here anyway in case I'm missing something.

---

PS:
I tried implementing the second code snipped but was getting all kinds of error messages. So I was thinking more about if the concept itself makes sense rather than trying to make the implementation work.

Comment: The promise and its lifecycle exist only in the runtime where it was instantiated. It may make sense to respond immediately rather than wait for underlying async stuff, but that's a separate issue *(and you still wouldn't respond w/ a promise)*.

Comment: standard http communication is half duplex, for this idea to work you need full duplex communication like websockets, which are not exactly promises, but it can be very similar

Comment: HTTP is a wire protocol. What exactly do you expect the promise to be serialised as?

Comment: What is the difference between promises and a fileStream as discussed in (https://www.mariokandut.com/how-to-stream-to-an-http-response-in-node-js/)? Or why is a promise not serializable but a FileStram is? I don't understand how one of them can be sent as a response but not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I understand fetch returns a promise that as soon as the api --here /movies-- responds, is resolved.

No, the promise is returned *immediately* from the function. A promise is an object that is basically a way for a caller to handle a 'future result'. A promise of a result if you will, but the promise is there right away. It resolves later.

> I'm wondering if there is any usecase where the API endpoint itself returns a promise as anresponse to an HTTP request. Something like

You seem to be talking about HTTP apis here. Typically with HTTP APIs the data that is returned is JSON (or XML, or Protobuf). A promise is not serializable as these formats, because promises isn't just data. It's code to handle events.

> . But the API would send the promise immediatly and then have a free cpu for doing other stuff.

Keep in mind that a promise is not some magical capsule that contains some operation running outside the CPU. Whatever promise you send back, will have to be resolved by *some code* that is still running. You can't offload that work to another computer (or browser) just by sending an event handler over, even if this were possible.

It would be a bit like sending a callback to a client. Something still needs to *call* that callback, and that something is likely doing the heavy lifting. Not the callback itself.

Comment: That the promise is returned immediately, I understood. The 'future result' is the resolve, as I had written, right?

I was not restricted to HTML APIs but had them in mind when writing the question. The fact that the promise is not serializable is interesting. That may be why it cannot be sent as an HTTP response.

Yes, the last part is also clear. The more I think about it, the more I believe that sending a promise does not fulfil any purpose. The API eventually has to send the data to the client, no matter if that data is the resolve of a promise or JSON.

Comment: @jo_rob yep I think you got it. I assumed this was more of a hypothetical question, but if you also had a real underlying problem you were trying to solve, this was probably not the right avenue.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP methods such as `fetch` are implementing **stream api**.

> The Fetch API uses Request and Response *objects*
> [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

> Response.body - A *ReadableStream* of the body contents.
> [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

> The ReadableStream interface of the Streams API represents a readable
> stream of byte data. The Fetch API offers a concrete instance of a
> ReadableStream through the body property of a Response object. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Following your links, I eventually found the following article (https://www.mariokandut.com/how-to-stream-to-an-http-response-in-node-js/), which shows how to pipe a stream into a response. Now if a promise is just a stream, it should be able to pipe it into a response as well, but I have yet to find an example of how to achieve that.

Comment: Ok, I think that a promise is just more than a simple stream and thus is not serializable. In particular the event handler that calls the resolve or reject methods are not meaningful when they are deserialized. Is this correct? That would explain it for me at least.